# Having trouble importing CSV into a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I am new to Stackoverflow and SQL Server.

I have a CSV file of some stats from a modded Minecraft server I'm running and thought it would be fun to import it into SQL Server because I've recently started to learn it. I've tried using the "SQL Server Import and Export Wizard" but I keep getting this error:

[image: error].

I'm using SSMS.

In the screenshot, it references data row 18, which reads:

```
 "craftItem.appliedenergistics2.nether_quartz_cutting_knife, null, null, 2"
```

If anyone has any idea what the issue is or knows a better way of doing this, I'd appreciate the help very much :)

Comment: MySQL with SSMS - does that work?

Comment: The error also mentions truncation, what are the datatypes?

Comment: I've removed [tag:mysql] as the above image is clearly from the data import wizard in SSMS, which is an IDE for SQL Server ; though I have also removed [tag:ssms] as the question and solution aren't actually related to it.

Comment: By the way, errors are better posted as text. I can barely read the image

Comment: I'd say that you have set up one column as NOT NULL and the data you are trying to import is having some NULL values in it

Comment: By reading the error codes, seems like the data you are trying to import doesn't fit into the column. Try increasing varchar for 'stat' column, you can do varchar(max) if you are not too concerned about the size of the table

Answer (score 0):

The error mentions data truncation, this is nearly always that the text in one of the fields in the csv file exceeds the size of the field you are trying to insert into.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the error message; too small.  Can you make a copy of the file, delete all but, let's say the first 3-5 rows, and try to do the import again?  Does it work?  Try different numbers of rows.  You may have some white characters, or some kind of non-printable characters, especially at the end of the file.